# Breakout game with c++(SDL2) - Trying to get ball to change trajectory with some issues

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I'm trying to get the ball to change trajectory in a very basic way. Basically what I've tried to code is; if the ball hits the edge of the screen `x axis` on the x or `right axis`, the `direction` will `reverse` accordingly. This can be seen in this `function`. A `struct` contains `pos_`,`speed_`, and `dir_` for the ball and an enumeration contains `directionx`. However, the ball just travels to the edge of the screen and does not move. I'd appreciate any light shed on how this isn't working.

```
void MoveBall()
{
for (auto &p : ball)
{
    if (p.dir == Direction::Directionx)
    {
        p.pos.x += p.speed;

        p.pos.y -= p.speed;
        if ((p.pos.x >= sizeX) || (p.pos.x <= 20))
        {
            p.pos.x -= p.speed;
            p.pos.y += p.speed;
        }
        if ((p.pos.y >= sizeY) || (p.pos.y <= 20))
        {
            p.pos.y += p.speed;
            p.pos.x -= p.speed;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you used a debugger on this to see what's happening with your variables when it hits the edge?

Comment: What is `ball`? Your text states it is a struct instance but then you wouldn't be able to use it in a range based for loop ? Or are there multiple balls ?

Comment: I tried to comment earlier. ball is an instance of a struct stored in a vector array. It is possible that I will have multiple instances later. Why would I need to use it in a range based loop?

Comment: @DarraghO'Piondair : You're already using a range based loop, which is impossible if ball was just a struct - That was confusing me.

Comment: I was basing it off an online tutorial. I ruled the enumeration class out and I'm working on the problem now. I'll let you know how it progresses. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the purpose of `if (p.dir == Direction::Directionx) {...}` is, but it would seem that the problem lies in this section of the code

```
    p.pos.x += p.speed;
    p.pos.y -= p.speed;
    if ((p.pos.x >= sizeX) || (p.pos.x <= 20))
    {
        p.pos.x -= p.speed;
        p.pos.y += p.speed;
    }
    if ((p.pos.y >= sizeY) || (p.pos.y <= 20))
    {
        p.pos.y += p.speed;
        p.pos.x -= p.speed;
    }
```

When one of these two if statements are true, your function effectively does nothing because the code inside the if statements nullify the earlier statements

```
p.pos.x += p.speed;
p.pos.y -= p.speed;
```

So when you hit the edge of the screen, you actually set

```
p.pos.x += 0;
p.pos.y -= 0;
```

So make sure you don't perform the first two update statements if one of the if statements are true.
EDIT:
A better way to set reversed speed is

```
    p.speed *= -1;
```

Comment: This fixed my code. Thanks very much and thanks to everyone that helped.